# Can "handmade" be used as a past participle?

Tags: past-participles

Can "handmade" be used as a past participle?

I'm looking at this sentence: "… all of our organic products are handmade locally."

Is it OK to use handmade this way? I think of handmade as an adjective only, but since it includes "made," maybe this is OK as a past participle.

Answer (score 1):

A verb "to handmake" seems to be in some use, although it is rare. It would naturally have the past participle "handmade."

I could not find an entry for it in any of the free online dictionaries indexed by [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=handmake&ls=a). However, the Oxford English Dictionary says

> *trans.* To make by hand, as opposed to by machine.
>   
> [...]
>   
> 1914   *Pop. Mech.* Feb. 223/1   The [carriage wheel] spokes were hand-made with a drawing knife.
>   
> 1971   *Ebony* Mar. 67/1 (*advt.*)    He handmade the first sour mash Bourbon. We still use our hands in making Old Crow.
>   
> 2008   C. Cox *Vintage Shoes* 201/1   All of Choo's shoes were entirely handmade on the premises..—he was handmaking two pairs per day.

Whether or not this is the best wording is a different matter. It would be simple to say instead "made *by hand* locally" if you prefer the sound of that.

The adjective *handmade* is older, according to the OED, and much more commonly used than the verb *to handmake.* In general, compounds of the noun + gerund → noun type, or of the noun + past participle → adjective type, are more productive than compounds consisting of a noun + verb → verb. But it is not all that uncommon for such compound verbs to arise by analogy once there is an established noun or adjective based on the same roots. (Related: [What is the etymology of "blameshift"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377512)) Often the use of these compound verbs remains somewhat marginal.